# How to limit input() function to only one data type?

Tags: python-3.x

```
def get_height():
    
    height = input("Height: ")
    
    if(height.isnumeric() == False):
        get_height()
    
    height = int(height)
```

I want the user to be only able to input integers. I know that .isnumeric() outputs False for float values. When I put 1.5 in the terminal, the function get_height is called again then I put an int value like 3 and i get this error: invalid literal for int() with base 10. Shouldn't my height variable have already updated?

Comment: You have a recursive function (why?). `height` is a local variable. Its value in the first call to `get_height` has nothing to do with the value in the second call.

Comment: thank you. I fixed the function by  assigning a global variable height = 0 then doing:

global height
height = input("Height: ")

I have to look into global and local variables more and how they interact with functions.

Answer (score 1):

Convert to `int` and catch exception:

```
def get_height():
    while True:
        try:
            height = int(input("Height: "))
            # you can test here a valid height
            if height < 0:
                continue
        except ValueError:
            pass  # retry while height is not an integer
        else:
            break  # height is a valid number, break the loop
    return height
```

```
>>> get_height()
Height: no
Height: why?
Height: -1000
Height: 182

182
```